# Laravel 5 Eloquent where and or in Clauses

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

i try to get results from table with multiple where and/or clauses.

My SQL statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE m__Id = 46
AND
t_Id = 2
AND
(Cab = 2 OR Cab = 4)
```

How i can get this with Laravel Eloquent?

My Code in Laravel is:

```
$BType = CabRes::where('m_Id', '=', '46')
                        ->where('t_Id', '=', '2')
                        ->where('Cab', '2')
                        ->orWhere('Cab', '=', '4')
                        ->get();
```

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Using [advanced wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres):

```
CabRes::where('m__Id', 46)
      ->where('t_Id', 2)
      ->where(function($q) {
          $q->where('Cab', 2)
            ->orWhere('Cab', 4);
      })
      ->get();
```

Or, even better, using `whereIn()`:

```
CabRes::where('m__Id', 46)
      ->where('t_Id', 2)
      ->whereIn('Cab', $cabIds)
      ->get();
```

Comment: Thank You this is working :)
But how i can get this with a array for cab if my array likes:

arrCab[2,4,6]

Comment: Why is it better, and where does the variable `$cabIds` come from?

Comment: the second option is the best one

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a  Laravel table join related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149031/laravel-join-query-with-conditions?

Answer (score 37):

Also, if you have a variable,

```
CabRes::where('m_Id', 46)
      ->where('t_Id', 2)
      ->where(function($q) use ($variable){
          $q->where('Cab', 2)
            ->orWhere('Cab', $variable);
      })
      ->get();
```

Comment: Can you link where you got the 'use'?I didn't find it in my research.

Comment: @natghi https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#subquery-where-clauses

Answer (score 7):

When we use multiple `and` (where) condition with last (where + or where) the where condition fails most of the time. for that we can use the nested where function with parameters passing in that.

```
$feedsql = DB::table('feeds as t1')
                   ->leftjoin('groups as t2', 't1.groups_id', '=', 't2.id')
                    ->where('t2.status', 1)
                    ->whereRaw("t1.published_on <= NOW()") 
                    >whereIn('t1.groupid', $group_ids)
                   ->where(function($q)use ($userid) {
                            $q->where('t2.contact_users_id', $userid)
                            ->orWhere('t1.users_id', $userid);
                     })
                  ->orderBy('t1.published_on', 'desc')->get();
```

The above query validate all where condition then finally checks 
where t2.status=1 and 
(where t2.contact_users_id='$userid' or where t1.users_id='$userid')